# directConnect option is not working after upgrading to webdriver-manager 12.1.4

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

I used to run my protractor tests using directConnect: true option set.
The chromedriver I had at that time was chromedriver2.46

Now with the latest webdriver-manaegr12.1.4, the chromedriver was upgraded to `ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29})`

If I still continue to use `directConnect: true` and run my tests, I get the following error

`session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75
  (Driver info: chromedriver=75.0.3770.8 (681f24ea911fe754973dda2fdc6d2a2e159dd300-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#40}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.4 x86_64)`

Comment: Oh no! I will look into this in the next few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my very simple example: https://github.com/cnishina/protractor542-chrome74 It does not use a Docker container but it works for Chrome 74 with ChromeDriver 74.

## Chrome browser + ChromeDriver versions

The output error message looks like session was not created because you are trying to use ChromeDriver 75. I would refer to http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads to match the ChromeDriver version to the Chrome browser version. The latest Chrome browser version is 74 so ChromeDriver downloads 74.0.3729.131. If you are still on Chrome browser 71-73, you could use ChromeDriver 2.46. Moving forward, the browser major version and chromedriver version must match. So for Chrome 73, you could use 73.0.3683.68.

## Downloading different versions of ChromeDriver

If you need to download a different version of ChromeDriver, you could run the webdriver-manager command:  `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 73.0.3683.68` or to download 2.46, `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.46`.

Comment: Side note: the current Chrome version is now 75. To get this you'll need webdriver-manager 12.1.5